# Shows only last 10 min logs from log file

Tags: shell

Log File :-

```
LOCATION    CPIC (TCP/IP) on local host with Unicode
ERROR       Error Message
TIME        Mon May  4 11:37:17 2020
RELEASE     721
COMPONENT   CPIC (TCP/IP) with Unicode
VERSION     3
RC          473
LINE        9261
COUNTER     15

Changing trace level: handle 38331088 / destination (null) / level 0
```

Tried with below command to automatically get the last 10 minutes log.

```
sed -n "/ $(date +\%R -d "-10 min")/,$"p logfile.log | grep "ERROR"

no output displayed
```

```
Expected Output : Error message in Last 10 mins.
```

Any Solution ?

Comment: Can you clarify what "doesn't worked" mean. Any error message, any output ? It will help if you post few more lines of the log file, so it will be easier to comment on your solution, and provide alternative. Do you have data for every minute, or is it possible to have large gaps between records ?

Comment: More specific, how much data is in the log file ? If you have more than 1 month of data in a single file, you will need better date compare.Also, what is the expected output ?

Comment: how much data is in the log file ? ==> Last 1 Months log , Any error message, any output ? ==> No any error No output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The challenge in this case is that the 10 minute test requires comparison of timestamp. Using pattern matching on the exact time 10 minutes ago might fail, if there was no error in the exact minutes.

As an alternative, consider the following 'AWK' based solution. It will skip lines until it see a line matching the following:
* First token is TIME
* The day of the month matching today
* Time in last 10 minutes

```
awk -v DD=$(date +%-d -d '-10 min') -v WHEN="$(date +\%R -d '-10 min')" '
$1 == "TIME" && $4 == +DD && $5 >= WHEN { p=1 }
p { print }
' logfile
```

The solution can be improved to be more generic. Current implementation will not work well during the first 10 minutes after midnight. This can be addressed (if needed) by OP.